# How to get my testxml.php file to run after the submit button has been pressed?

Tags: php, xml

I have a submit form that is working correctly and adding the data where I need it.

I have a testxml.php that correctly outputs what I want into and XML file.
The problem is I can not figure out how to get my testxml.php file to run after the submit button has been pressed so that I get my updated test.xml file each time new data is entered.

Here are my 2 files.

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['j1stock'])){
echo "STOCK SCORE REQUIRED";
header( "refresh:2; ../judge1.php" );
(exit);
}    
if (empty($_POST['j1contestant'])){
echo "CONTESTANT SCORE REQUIRED";
header( "refresh:2; ../judge1.php" );
(exit);
}    
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "score"); 
$stock = $_POST['j1stock'];
$contestant = $_POST['j1contestant'];

if($link === false){ 
die("ERROR: Could not connect. "  
            . mysqli_connect_error()); 
} 

$sql = ("UPDATE jscores SET j1stock = '$stock', j1contestant = '$contestant' WHERE id = 0"); 

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ 
echo "SCORE SUBMITTED."; 
} else { 
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. "  
                        . mysqli_error($link); 
}  
mysqli_close($link); 
header( "refresh:2; ../judge1.php" );
?>
```

And My File that exports data into XML

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','tgreen','L3tm31n!','score');
$fire=mysqli_query($con,"select * from jscores");
$xml=new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI('test.xml');
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement('jscores');
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire))
{
    $xml->startElement('jscores');
        $xml->startElement('j1stock');
        $xml->writeRaw($row['j1stock']);
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->startElement('j1contestant');
        $xml->writeRaw($row['j1contestant']);
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->startElement('j2stock');
        $xml->writeRaw($row['j2stock']);
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->startElement('j2contestant');
        $xml->writeRaw($row['j2contestant']);
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->startElement('total');
        $xml->writeRaw($row['total']);
        $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();
?>
```

Comment: Ans yeas Dharman, I am learning to do those as we speak.  I am certainly aware of the importance of that.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to redirect to your `testxml.php` file after the form has been successfully processed, a simple redirection seems enought :

Just change this line, at the end of your file:

```
header( "refresh:2; ../judge1.php" );
```

By:

```
header('Location: testxml.php'); // Or your testxml.php URL
```

Comment: That absolutely worked.  Thank you so much.  I just had stared at it way to long.